# TestNG Emailable-report css lost after sending through Jenkins Gmail email notification

Tags: html, jenkins, testng

I am trying to send TestNG emailable-report.html result through Gmail after each build on Jenkins using

```
${FILE,path="directory_of_emailable_report.html"}
```

I set the Jenkins to trigger email send after each build. Somehow the emailable-report messed up like the css is not loaded as it is shown below:

[image]

Any idea on how to make gmail send the emailable-report as it is on the original html file?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Jenkins itself has a feature to attach any file in your project workspace. Assuming you are using Email Extension Plugin.

Now in your project configuration under your post build action u will find Editable Email notification, add it to post build action and fill all relevant details, now in text field labelled "Attachments",

just enter: **/emailable-report.html

[image: Screenshot]

It will automatically fetch your report in project workspace and attach it.

Hope this will do your job :)

Comment: That is a way to attach report in email. Here target is to show results in email body, not in attachment. I'm facing same issue. CSS is lost when the `emailable-report.html` is opened through Jenkins workspace or when it is sent through email. Whereas if the same file is opened through Eclipse workspace, it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I use a modified version of [Mohammad's answer](/a/39178152/11107541). Instead of `**/emailable-report.html`, which attaches the report twice in the email, I just used asterisk once `*`. This is entered in project configuration under post build action > Editable Email notification, in a post build action > "Attachments",